# Perl Connect to MSSQL Database Engine

Tags: sql-server, perl

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create a Perl script to run a simple SELECT statement on a MSSQL Database I have access to.

The database I am connecting to authenticates with SQL Server Authentication. I found [this](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html) but I don't think it applies because it is for ODBC.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you referenced is absolutely the right track.  You'll be using an ODBC connection to talk to MS SQL Server.  Otherwise, you can use DBD::Sybase to connect (SQL Server grew out of the Sybase code-base, so they share the underlying protocol, which is why the drivers for Sybase can be used).

I would recommend using Microsoft's official ODBC driver with DBD::ODBC over DBD::Sybase.

Comment: I was able to use [this](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/comments223a.html?sid=18337) to solve my issue of connecting. I [have another issue now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035931) though

Answer (score 0):

You didn't find any useful links? 
I'm using MSSQL server for DB connection as below:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:Sybase:database=DBNAME;server=DBSERVER",
            "User", "Password", { PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 } )
          or die "Cant connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Table");
    $sth->execute();
    $value = $sth->fetchrow_array();
```

Comment: What exactly is Sybase? I am getting `install_driver(Sybase) failed: Can't locate DBD/Sybase.pm`

Comment: Sybase it is a database and you need to install DBD::Sybase for the above connection to work on MsSQL. Like DBD::MySQL.http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Sybase.pm