# Perl Not Reading Full Values from Database

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc

I am currently using the `DBI` module to connect to my MSSQL Database to pull some data from a table.

The row I am trying to pull contains a lot of text (it is of type `ntext` and can contain up to 6Mb of text).

My query is a very simple one at the moment:

```
my $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [reportRow] from UsageReport";
```

And I also have `LongTruncOk` enabled for the Database options.

After I execute the query, I want to display the rows.

```
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
   print "@row\n";
}
```

Unfortunately it displays the data in a very weird manner with spaces in between every character and it only retrieves the first 40 characters.

```
< r e p o r t > < r e p o r t h e a d e r > < m o n t h > O c t o b e r   2 0
```

If I use `File::Slurp` to output `@row` to a file, it displays as

[image]

Is there a reason the data is being cut off and is being displayed weird?

Edit: How would I convert UTF16 into a format that doesn't insert spaces between characters?

Comment: probably utf16 chars being displayed in some other charset, e.g. iso8859...

Comment: How would I change the charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `LongReadLen` in addition to `LongTruncOk`.  You've told DBI it's ok to cut off long results from the DB, and now you need to tell it how long of a string you're willing to accept.

Comment: Yes this was the solution. I ended up setting `LongReadLen` to 10000000 and I did not have to set `LongTruncOk`